# Save a image from a URL

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I want to grab a set of images using the URL in PHP. I've tried using `file_get_contents` and `curl`. Below is the code that I have tried using.

```
$image = file_get_contents('http://user:pwd@server/directory/images/image1.jpg');
file_put_contents('D:/images/image1.jpg', $image);
```

and

```
$url = 'http://server/directory/images/image1.jpg';
$localFilePath = 'D:/images/image1.jpg';
$ch = curl_init ($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
$raw = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
if(file_exists($localFilePath)){
    unlink($localFilePath);
}
$fp = fopen($localFilePath,'wb');
fwrite($fp, $raw);
fclose($fp);
```

In both cases, I am getting the following error:

```
401 - Unauthorized : Access is denied due to invalid credentials.
```

The password has a special character. I can't change it to a plain password, as the password policies don't allow it.

Comment: When using `file_get_contents()` you'll need to create a special stream context containing the Authentication header. The curl code should be fine. What is the special character ?

Comment: Is the special character escaped?

Comment: The special character is underscore. Not sure, how to escape it.

Comment: @hek2mgl I tried using context as below.
$context = stream_context_create(array(
 'http' => array(
  'header' => "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode("user:Pwd_123")
 )
));
Still same error.

Answer (score 0):

I Don't see the place where you tell CURL to use AUTHentication:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
```

I think it also might be because you're not using cookies, enable them:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies.txt");
```

Comment: Well, I've tried using CURLOPT_USERPWD. But that didn't help.

Comment: added this to the code: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'user:Pwd_123');
Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent of this line is

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "user:pwd");
```

This one, and you can try this by replacing your one

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, 
      array("Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode("user:pwd")));

// also you can try by changing + / characters into _-
```

Now come to the point. Base64 has several implementation based on RFC. For example : [RFC3538](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html). Different library or different language implemented different RFC for base64 encoding/decoding. For example at some implementation it uses `+` and `/` character and some use the `_` and `-` character.

So lets say your curl is sending the base64 string for the authorization is `xyz+12=` but your server is expecting the string to be as `xyz_12=`. So it will obviously fail to decode.